# Syntax error on semi-colon in MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting the following error and I don't know why:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ';

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE staffnewid_all()
BEGIN
DECLARE x int;
DECLARE y int;
DECLARE z int;

DECLARE charid varchar;
DECLARE a int;
DECLARE b int;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS cms_psm.temp_nostaf;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cms_psm.temp_nostaf (tempid INTEGER NOT   NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, char_id varchar(1));

INSERT INTO cms_psm.temp_nostaf (char_id) SELECT DISTINCT(LEFT(nostaf, 1)) FROM staf_new_no;

SET a = (SELECT min(tempid) FROM cms_psm.temp_nostaf ORDER BY tempid);
SET b = (SELECT COUNT(tempid) FROM cms_psm.temp_nostaf);


WHILE a<=b DO

SET charid = (SELECT char_id FROM cms_psm.temp_nostaf WHERE tempid=a);

SET x = (SELECT count(*) FROM staf_peribadi WHERE nostaf LIKE CONCAT('%', charid, '%') ORDER BY nostaf ASC);
SET y = (SELECT min(id) FROM staf_new_no WHERE nostaf LIKE CONCAT('%', charid, '%') ORDER BY nostaf ASC);
SET z = 1;



WHILE z<=x DO
  UPDATE staf_new_no SET nostaf_new = CONCAT(charid, LPAD(z, 6, '0')) WHERE id=y;
  SET z = z + 1 ;
  SET y = y + 1 ;
END WHILE;

SET a = a + 1 ;

END WHILE;

END
```

Comment: What happens after your query? You never use `$$` to show the end of the procedure, and you never set the delimiter back to the semi-colon. I suspect one of those is causing you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

End your code with the statement

```
END;$$ 
Delimiter ;
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

actually i forgot this

```
DECLARE charid varchar;
```

it should be

```
DECLARE charid varchar(1);
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE x int;
DECLARE y int;
DECLARE z int;
DECLARE a int;
DECLARE b int;
DECLARE charid varchar(1);

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_nostaf;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_nostaf (tempid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, char_id varchar(1));

INSERT INTO temp_nostaf (char_id) SELECT DISTINCT(LEFT(nostaf, 1)) FROM staf_new_no;

SET a = (SELECT min(tempid) FROM cms_psm.temp_nostaf ORDER BY tempid);
SET b = (SELECT COUNT(tempid) FROM cms_psm.temp_nostaf);


WHILE a<=b DO

SET charid = (SELECT char_id FROM cms_psm.temp_nostaf WHERE tempid=a);

SET x = (SELECT count(*) FROM staf_peribadi WHERE nostaf LIKE CONCAT('%', charid, '%') ORDER BY nostaf ASC);
SET y = (SELECT min(id) FROM staf_new_no WHERE nostaf LIKE CONCAT('%', charid, '%') ORDER BY nostaf ASC);
SET z = 1;



WHILE z<=x DO
  UPDATE staf_new_no SET nostaf_new = CONCAT(charid, LPAD(z, 6, '0')) WHERE id=y;
  SET z = z + 1 ;
  SET y = y + 1 ;
END WHILE;

SET a = a + 1 ;

END WHILE;

END
```